# React Native, How to post FormData in Webview

Tags: react-native, webview, multipartform-data, form-data

All,

In my project I want to post FormData in Webview, We can use source to post normal body and method, But How to post formdata? Can we directly give the give appended data to body?

```
   <form method="POST" action="https://domain_name/secur/frontdoor.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="sid"
      value="full_sessionID_value" />
<input type="hidden" name="retURL" 
      value="optional_relative_url_to_open" />
```

Answer (score 2):

check it out... it will automatically submit your form... otherwise add a button and submit through that button.... you may check you console to find out current url that you WebView hitting

```
 <WebView source={{ html: 
                    `<body onload="document.FormName.submit()">
                        <form name=“FormName” method="POST" action="abc.com”>
                            <input  name=“mobileNum” value=“+923521234567”>
                            <input name=“emaill” value="test@test.com">
                        </form>
                    </body>`
                     }}
                                onMessage={this.onMessage}
                                onNavigationStateChange={(getUrl) => {
                                    console.log("getUrl", getUrl)
                                }}
                            />
```

Answer (score 1):

The `source` prop will be the following in your case:

```
{
  uri: "https://domain_name/secur/frontdoor.jsp",
  body: "sid=full_sessionID_value&retURL=optional_relative_url_to_open",
  method: "POST"
}
```

In general, the body will be your keys and their corresponding values concatenated with an &. So `key1=value1&key2=value2` etc.

Answer (score -1):

Do it like that

```
const body = new FromBody()
body.append("sid",value)
```